# Is combining rest api calls to reduce # requests worth doing?

Tags: performance, rest

My server used to handle 700+ user burst and now it is failing at around 200 users.
(Users are connecting to the server almost at the same time after clicking a push message)

I think the change is due to the change how the requests are made.

Back then, webserver collected all the information in a single response in an html.
Now, each section in a page is making a rest api request resulting in probably 10+ more requests.

I'm considering making an api endpoint to aggregate those requests for pages that users would open when they click on push notification.

Another solution I think of is caching those frequently used rest api responses.

Is it a good idea to combine api calls to reduce api calls ?

Answer (score 3):

It is always a good idea to reduce API calls. The optimal solution is to get all the necessary data in one go without any unused information.
This results in less traffic, less requests (and loads) to the server, less RAM and CPU usage, as well as less concurrent DB operations.

Caching is also a great choice. You can consider both caching the entire request and separate parts of the response.

A combined API response means that there will be just one response, which will reduce the pre-execution time (where the app is loading everything), but will increase the processing time, because it's doing everything in one thread. This will result in less traffic, but a slightly slower response time.

From the user's perspective this would mean that if you combine everything, the page will load slower, but when it does it will load up entirely.

It's a matter of finding the balance.

And for the question if it's worth doing - it depends on your set-up. You should measure the start-up time of the application and the execution time and do the math.

Another thing you should consider is the amount of time this might require. There is also the solution of increasing the server power, like creating a clustered cache and using a load balancer to split the load. You should compare the needed time for both tasks and work from there.